# Restore session (reopen windows) after a **CLI** shutdown on Big Sur

Tags: command-line, big-sur, automation, shutdown, sudo

I'm automating some tasks, like brew upgrade then shutdown, or Duplicati backup (no Time Machine), wait for cloud sync then shutdown, but I can't seem to find a CLI command which WILL reopen my windows/restore session on the next boot.

I've tried one of these, also added them to NOPASSWD sudoers:

```
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/halt
```

but I can't seem to find one which actually restores the session too.

Is this feature implemented and available from CLI? (Usually when I shut my Macbook down, I use the Apple menu, but a script can't click for me, can it?)

I have a 2018 15" MacBook Pro with the latest Big Sur (`11.6.2 (20G314)`).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your, e.g., `bash/zsh` *shell script* you can use e.g.:

```applescript
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to restart'
```

Or:

```applescript
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to shut down'
```

Then any open *applications* and their *window* will be restored, assuming you have not unchecked **[√] Reopen windows when logging back in** on the standard **restart** and **shut down** *dialog box*, e.g.:

[image]

Note that you will not see this *dialog box* when using the *commands* shown above.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference if you run `shutdown` from the shell.  If the option is set, your windows will be re-opened.

Comment: That option was set, but after a `shutdown`, nothing was restored. Will try user3439894's suggestion tonight. Thanks

Comment: I tried it today. The problem was that Cisco AnyConnect interrupted the shutdown, so it did nothing, was waiting there for the dialog to be pressed 'ok'. Is there a way to override these interruptions (other than `kill -9 APP`)? As this is no automation like this, if some stuff can just interrupt it.

Comment: @user3439894 any suggestion for the above?